# Convert multiple list variables in to a matrix of desired arrangement

Tags: r

I have the below list of variables which I would like to convert to a matrix with a customized desired arrangement,

```
m1 <- c("10","12","13")
m2 <- c("5","6")
m3 <- c("4")
```

I would like to combine the above 3 list values into the below matrix structure where the arrangement is based on the Index of each list. If index(1) is present in all the lists it should take that value in the matrix generation. If there are no corresponding Index value, then it should allot the previous Index value.  The  number of rows is formed by the max value of the individual list,

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   10   12   13
[2,]    5    6    6
[3,]    4    4    4
```

I tried to run with the below code,

```
mat <- matrix(c(m1,m2,m3),ncol=3,byrow = TRUE)
```

but the output of the generated matrix is,

```
[,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   10   13    6
[2,]   12    5    4
```

Comment: Try `rbind(m1,m2,m3)` and manually set `mat[2,3] <- 6` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mylist <- list(m1, m2, m3)

#make all vectors the same length
mylist <- lapply(mylist, "length<-", max(lengths(mylist)))

#last observation carried forward
library(zoo)
mylist <- lapply(mylist, na.locf)

#rbind
m <- do.call(rbind, mylist)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "10" "12" "13"
#[2,] "5"  "6"  "6" 
#[3,] "4"  "4"  "4"
```

Comment: When the list only has single values, (eg., m1 <- 10, m2 <- 5, m3 <- 4. The above code generates,   [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
[1,] "10"  "10"  "10" 
[2,] "5"  "5"  "5" 
[3,] "4"    "4"    "4"      But what I would like is   [,1]     
[1,] "10"   
[2,] "5"   
[3,] "4"  It should be able to handle when the variable list has only one value or  multiple values (the list is generated dynamically)

Comment: @SSK "The above code generates ..." That's just not correct. You are not running the code shown here if you get that output.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I had used a previously generated list while calculating the length. It works fine! Thanks.